# TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough'

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am  try to create Transformation Pipeline for housing data

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
rooms_ix, bedrooms_ix, population_ix, household_ix = 3,4,5,6
class CombineAttributesAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, add_bedrooms_per_room = True):
        self.add_bedrooms_per_room = add_bedrooms_per_room
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transfrom(self, X, y=None):
        rooms_per_househond = X[:,rooms_ix]/X[:,household_ix]
        population_per_household = X[:,population_ix]/ X[:, household_ix]
        if self.add_bedrooms_per_room:
            bedrooms_per_room = X[:,bedrooms_ix]/X[:rooms_ix]
            return np.c_[X, rooms_per_househond, population_per_household, bedrooms_per_room]
        else:
            return np.c_[X, rooms_per_househond, population_per_household]
```

My Pipeline code which i used for Pipeline  :-

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
num_pipline = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median')),
    ('attribs_adder', CombineAttributesAdder(add_bedrooms_per_room=False)),
    ('stand_scaler', StandardScaler()),
])
housing_num_transform = num_pipline.fit_transform(housing_num)
```

It trough Error :-
[image]

Comment: You defined the `transfrom` method, but meant `transform`.

Comment: Please add more details which line I need to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body of your `CombineAttributesAdder` class, you misspelled the word `transform`. The method definition should look like this:

```py
class CombineAttributesAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, add_bedrooms_per_room = True):
        self.add_bedrooms_per_room = add_bedrooms_per_room

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):  # <-- not 'transfrom'
        ...
```

For each transformer, `Pipeline` objects will call `fit_transform`  which, in turn, will call the methods `fit` and `transform`. Because of this typo, the program cannot find the corresponding method and throws the error.